# What is a good automated test tool to test UI of Java Swing based windows application

Tags: java, automation, automated-tests

I am looking for suggestions on automated testing tools that can be used to test GUI/Frontend of Java Swing based windows applications in automated fashion ?

Comment: Is the application already developed or the development is still ongoing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Fest has a module](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/FEST/Swing+Module) for functional Swing testing, and it's actively maintained.

Answer (score 1):

windows test case tool is there its eclipse plugin,
Marathon tool is there

Answer (score 1):

I suggest [JFCUnit](http://jfcunit.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you want. If you want recording Marathon (http://www.marathontesting.com) might be a good choice. Marathon records scripts in Ruby or Python.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to take a look at [ReTest](https://www.retest.de/en/). It is a innovative tool with a novel approach to functional regression testing, which it combines with ai-based monkey testing.

It is about to become open source as well.

Disclaimer: I am one of the founders of the company behind ReTest.